# Есть сайт на нем реализовано находясь на любой секции при клике через share button можно поделиться этой секцией?

Tags: javascript

Есть сайт http://www.rodelde.org/ataglance/  на нем реализовано находясь на любой секции при клике через share button можно поделиться этой секцией.
Каким образом реализовать такое? чтобы находясь на секции можно поделиться именно ссылкой на секцию

Answer (score 0):

Можно так, если блок "Поделиться" на каждой секции свой. С фиксированным сайдбаром придется подзаморочиться

```js
const share = document.querySelector('.share'),
  section = document.querySelector('.section-wrapper'),
  shareLink = document.querySelector('.share-txt');

share.addEventListener('click', e => {
  shareLink.value = `${window.location.href}${section.href}`;
});
```

```html
<a href="#some-section" class="section-wrapper"></a>
<input type="button" value="share!" class="share">
<input type="text" class="share-txt">
```